# Creating new CT from template hosted on remote SMB server

Tags: proxmox

I've created a new share on my TrueNAS to host ct templates for my proxmox cluster.

I added the share successfully and I was able to download the templates to the share from the OVU Web UI.

However, when I try to create new CT using one the templates I get this error:

```
Logical volume "vm-102-disk-0" created.
Creating filesystem with 2621440 4k blocks and 655360 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 3f65907d-b6e9-42f3-88e5-6431f76d35f2
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632
Logical volume "vm-102-disk-1" created.
Creating filesystem with 26214400 4k blocks and 6553600 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 376df9d3-1757-4785-840c-8d6f8640bb31
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872
extracting archive '/mnt/pve/jadzia-ct-templates/template/cache/debian-12-turnkey-nextcloud_18.0-1_amd64.tar.gz'
tar: Skipping to next header
Total bytes read: 1791139840 (1.7GiB, 109MiB/s)
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Logical volume "vm-102-disk-0" successfully removed.
Logical volume "vm-102-disk-1" successfully removed.
TASK ERROR: unable to create CT 102 - command 'lxc-usernsexec -m u:0:100000:65536 -m g:0:100000:65536 -- tar xpf - -z --totals --one-file-system -p --sparse --numeric-owner --acls --xattrs '--xattrs-include=user.*' '--xattrs-include=security.capability' '--warning=no-file-ignored' '--warning=no-xattr-write' -C /var/lib/lxc/102/rootfs --skip-old-files --anchored --exclude './dev/*'' failed: exit code 2
```

I do not get this error if I create the CT from a template stored on one of the pve node's local storage.

I've not been able to make any progress in troubleshooting this.

The share is owned by proxmox/proxmox on TrueNAS, which has full access to the share and the unix filesystem.